# Circular effect in rectangle

Tags: css, rectangles

I'm trying to make a design as shown in image, but main issue is that I cant use z-index there because it will effect other elements. Is there any way to achieve this ? Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like this with pseudo-element.

```css
.element {
  width: 400px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.element:after {
  content: '';
  width: 210%;
  height: 700px;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```